# Bet process when 2 players and Big blind is all in on the Pre-Flop

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

as I understand when 2 players playing no Limit Hold-em

1. ***dealerButton*** is ***smallBlind***
2. ***bigBlind*** goes All-In at the preflop.
3. ***smallBlind*** opens the game and he CALL.

how does the game move forward? (does the ***smallBlind*** have the option to see the flop-turn-river by keeping checking or betting on his own sidepot?) or does the game end as soon as the ***smallBlind*** makes his first choice?

Comment: smallBlind can either fold or call, if he/she calls (or all-in if not enough cash) then there is only the matter of showing the last cards. The big blind cannot raise further, so call will be the last betting action from the players that round.

Comment: Hi @TobiasWärre, thank you for your reply. So if for example, the smallBlind "Calls",   both players have the option of "check", and reveal the flop-turn-river?    - also if you don't mind, what happens if both players go all-in, can both players take "check" action until the showdown?

Comment: @Tobias Make sure you are putting answers as an actual answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: @bwarner, I've been drive-by answering to much to trust that the question is still the same later on, Most downvotes I've had is because of changes to the question after me trying to answer it. So I just left it as a comment since it wasn't that elaborate.

Comment: @FelipeZuleta In response to your comments, a player who has bet all-in takes no further action. If all but one of the players in a pot are all-in and betting has resolved, all players reveal their hands and the remaining cards are played out.

Comment: Do you mean that the player with the BB button doesn't have enough to cover the big blind, so their blind is all-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the big blind goes all in that leaves the small bline with one chose if they would like to continue and see the hand and that is to call the bet by either going all in if they don't have enough to cover the bet or call it by betting the required amount. This is similar to if the big blind did a raise on the pre flop as the small blind would still need to match the difference.

In this case betting would end, both players would reveal their cards and the dealer would play the deck until all 5 cards have been played and a winner has been determined. There would be no side pot as in a two player game there is no other player to bet against so the only money that could be in the side pot would be the small blind's.